# Child component does not set the initial value passed from the parent: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to implement a settings page where I have a global settings and some kind of child settings(in form of a slider).

I am unable to set the initial that is being passed from the parent.

I am handling the following scenarios:

1)When all of the child settings is on , then parents switch state should be turned on state

2)When any of the child settings is off, then parents switch state should be switched to pending

3)When all of the child settings is off, then parents switch state should be switched to off state

4) Also On click of button, I need to get the current state of all the child components.

If add an setState inside componentDidMount inside parent(may be API call will be written inside of it , so that initial states of the switches will be set accordingly and then be able to change) , The child switches should be able to get the state value right , But here it does not.

And I also see that toggling is happening in the wrong way. Here it is happening once you click on the already selected one which is ideally wrong

Have tried the following approach but it does not seem like working. For this , I am using react-multi-toggle for this toggle switch.

Can someone help here ?

Code Sandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-yn3fh

### App

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChildSwitch from "./ChildSwitch";
import ParentSwitch from "./ParentSwitch";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      parentVal: "disabled",
      switch1Val: "disabled",
      switch2Val: "disabled",
      switch3Val: "disabled"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      switch1Val: "enabled",
      switch2Val: "disabled",
      switch3Val: "enabled"
    });
  }

  onGetChildSwitchValues = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  setChildSwitchValue = (whichSwitch, value) => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => Object.assign({}, prevState, { [whichSwitch]: value }),
      this.setParentSwitchValue
    );
  };

  setParentSwitchValue = () => {
    const { switch1Val, switch2Val, switch3Val } = this.state;
    const switchStates = [switch1Val, switch2Val, switch3Val];
    const parent = switchStates.every(this.isEnabled)
      ? "enabled"
      : switchStates.every(this.isDisabled)
      ? "disabled"
      : "pending";
    this.setState({ parentVal: parent });
  };

  isEnabled(value) {
    return value === "enabled";
  }

  isDisabled(value) {
    return value === "disabled";
  }

  render() {
    const { parentVal, switch1Val, switch2Val, switch3Val } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        Parent Switch :{" "}
        <ParentSwitch
          parentSwitch={parentVal}
          onSelect={this.setParentSwitchValue}
        />
        Child Switches :
        <ChildSwitch
          childSwitch={switch1Val}
          switchName={"switch1Val"}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <ChildSwitch
          childSwitch={switch2Val}
          switchName={"switch2Val"}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <ChildSwitch
          childSwitch={switch3Val}
          switchName={"switch3Val"}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onGetChildSwitchValues}>Get Child Values</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

### Parent

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";
import "react-multi-toggle/style.css";

class ParentSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled",
          optionClass: "red"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Pending",
          value: "pending",
          optionClass: "grey"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled",
          optionClass: "green"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { options } = this.state;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={this.props.parentSwitch}
        onSelectOption={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ParentSwitch;
```

### Child

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";

export default class ChildSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled",
          optionClass: "red"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled",
          optionClass: "green"
        }
      ],
      selected: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ selected: this.props.childSwitch });
  }

  onSelectOption = selected => {
    if (selected === "disabled") {
      this.setState({ selected: "enabled" }, () =>
        this.props.onSelect(this.props.switchName, "enabled")
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({ selected: "disabled" }, () =>
        this.props.onSelect(this.props.switchName, "disabled")
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { options, selected } = this.state;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={selected}
        onSelectOption={this.onSelectOption}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to control the state of your parent and child multiselect from the main component `index.js`. It will best if it is the only source of truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to solve this is to control parent and child switches from master component.
Checkout the [working forked codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-0zqd1)

**APP**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChildSwitch from "./ChildSwitch";
import ParentSwitch from "./ParentSwitch";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      parentVal: "disabled",
      switch1Val: "enabled",
      switch2Val: "disabled",
      switch3Val: "enabled"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setParentSwitchValue();
  }

  onGetChildSwitchValues = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  setChildSwitchValue = (whichSwitch, selected) => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ ...prevState, [whichSwitch]: selected }),
      this.setParentSwitchValue
    );
  };

  setParentSwitchValue = () => {
    const { switch1Val, switch2Val, switch3Val } = this.state;
    const switchStates = [switch1Val, switch2Val, switch3Val];
    let parent = "pending";

    if (switchStates.every(val => val === "enabled")) {
      parent = "enabled";
    }

    if (switchStates.every(val => val === "disabled")) {
      parent = "disabled";
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, parentVal: parent }));
  };

  render() {
    const { parentVal, switch1Val, switch2Val, switch3Val } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        Parent Switch :{" "}
        <ParentSwitch
          parentSwitch={parentVal}
          onSelect={this.setParentSwitchValue}
        />
        Child Switches :
        <ChildSwitch
          switchName={"switch1Val"}
          selected={switch1Val}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <ChildSwitch
          switchName={"switch2Val"}
          selected={switch2Val}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <ChildSwitch
          switchName={"switch3Val"}
          selected={switch3Val}
          onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onGetChildSwitchValues}>Get Child Values</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Parent**

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";
import "react-multi-toggle/style.css";

class ParentSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled",
          optionClass: "red"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Pending",
          value: "pending",
          optionClass: "grey"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled",
          optionClass: "green"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { options } = this.state;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={this.props.parentSwitch}
        onSelectOption={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ParentSwitch;
```

**Child**

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";
import "react-multi-toggle/style.css";

class ParentSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled",
          optionClass: "red"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Pending",
          value: "pending",
          optionClass: "grey"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled",
          optionClass: "green"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { options } = this.state;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={this.props.parentSwitch}
        onSelectOption={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ParentSwitch;
```

Comment: Thanks much my man! Suppose there is a component with multiple parents with children switches , how can i implement a super parent component that gives me a consolidated values of all parent and children. so far it's only with one parent and 2 children.

Comment: @vjr you can have all your Switches get and set their values from the same state. Similarly as it has been done now.

Comment: would you please me out with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546099/get-consolidated-data-from-all-the-child-components-in-the-form-of-an-object-ins/57546196#57546196..I need it in a form of consolidated object

Comment: @vjr That post seems to work fine, what is your issue there? You want all the swtiches options in one place?

Comment: Just need a way to group switches and get all values. I might have a component where I have groups of parent and child switches and a submit button, that gives me the details of all. Like a component something like this { parent 1: child 1,child 2}, {parent 2:child1,child2} and on click of button i would want an object like { "group1": { parent1 : enabled, child 1: enabled, child 2: enabled },"group2": { parent 2: pending, child 1: enabled, child 2: disabled }. In the post, you can find only one group ! I want say 2 groups and then a consolidated object on click of the button

Comment: @Marlo Mbakop You can answer it here itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546099/get-consolidated-data-from-all-the-child-components-in-the-form-of-an-object-ins/57546196#57546196..I

Comment: @vjr, Got u. I will take a look

Comment: @vjr, check it out here, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-perfect-jc8dj, I'll explain the solution later on the post when I'm off office.

Comment: Thanks much although it is missing one thing: On change of parent to enabled, it should make its children enabled , same applies for disabled:)

Comment: @vjr but you said your parent switch is read only or i'm missing something?

Comment: Oh i missed it! Guess the comment isn't updated! It thought it was added. Sorry! Yeah, I wanted the above said behavior :) Parent should also be changeable ; Parent on green should turn all children to green ; On red it should be red ; But pending it should be as is :)

Comment: @vjr ok it is feasible, it will be another question. Do add  a sandbox, i'll check it out

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-multi-toggle-solution-perfect-wrx1w?codemirror=1... Thank you :)

Comment: @vjr, please open a new post

Comment: Just did:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592935/dynamically-add-classes-on-based-on-state-value-and-also-change-the-children-con

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198247/discussion-between-morlo-mbakop-and-vjr).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not updating the local state when the `childSwitch` property changes. So it will stay on the disabled state. To achieve this you have to add the `componentDidUpdate` method or just directly use the property without any local state.

In ChildSwitch

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.childSwitch !== this.props.childSwitch) {
      this.setState({ selected: this.props.childSwitch });
    }
  }
```

Working fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-8xnf3

Comment: But the parent state still remains red ? It should turn into grey incase any of the child switches is green. Guess this will not be covered with your answer. Also your sandbox is still is same as mine. May be you have not saved it:)

Comment: Sorry. What was missing is the call of `setParentSwitchValue` in `index.js` after setting the child values. Now it should cover all your cases.

Comment: Thanks much for the answer ! Suppose there is a component with multiple parents with children switches , how can i implement a super parent component that gives me a consolidated values of all parent and children. so far it's only with one parent and 2 children