# Get consolidated data from all the child components in the form of an object inside a parent component : React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, setstate

I am implementing a setting page for an application. For each setting I have implemented a slider that has enabled(green) or disabled(red) state. But parent's settings is read only and is calculated based on the values of its children.

Parent's setting is derived as follows: If all children are red, parent stays red ; If all are green parent stays green; If at-least one of child is green then parent stays grey(Pending).

These settings are grouped something like this:

Parent Feature 1 :  (read-only-toggle)

```
 Setting 1   (Toggle)

 Setting 2   (Toggle)
```

Parent Feature 2:   (read-only-toggle)

```
Setting 1   (Toggle)

Setting 2   (Toggle)
```

And in the end there is also a button, that gives me a consolidated values of all parent and children. But so far I was able to do only with one parent and 2 children.

Can someone help with an approach of getting consolidated values of all the settings in one place(Like a super parent component where all these settings are configured).

For this , I am using react-multi-toggle for this toggle switch.

Help would be really appreciated.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-perfect-v9bi5

### App

```
import React from "react";
import ChildSwitch from "./ChildSwitch";
import ParentSwitch from "./ParentSwitch";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      parentVal: "disabled",
      switch1Val: "enabled",
      switch2Val: "disabled"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setParentSwitchValue();
  }

  onGetChildSwitchValues = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  setChildSwitchValue = (whichSwitch, selected) => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ ...prevState, [whichSwitch]: selected }),
      this.setParentSwitchValue
    );
  };

  setParentSwitchValue = () => {
    const { switch1Val, switch2Val } = this.state;
    const switchStates = [switch1Val, switch2Val];
    let parent = "pending";
    if (switchStates.every(val => val === "enabled")) {
      parent = "enabled";
    }
    if (switchStates.every(val => val === "disabled")) {
      parent = "disabled";
    }
    this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, parentVal: parent }));
  };

  render() {
    const { parentVal, switch1Val, switch2Val } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="boxed">
          Parent Setting 1 :{" "}
          <ParentSwitch
            parentSwitch={parentVal}
            onSelect={this.setParentSwitchValue}
          />
          Setting 1:
          <ChildSwitch
            switchName={"switch1Val"}
            selected={switch1Val}
            onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
          />
          Setting 2:
          <ChildSwitch
            switchName={"switch2Val"}
            selected={switch2Val}
            onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onGetChildSwitchValues}>Get All Values</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

### ChildSetting

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";

export default class ChildSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  onSelectOption = selected => {
    this.props.onSelect(this.props.switchName, selected);
  };

  render() {
    const { options } = this.state;
    const { selected } = this.props;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={selected}
        onSelectOption={this.onSelectOption}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

### Parent Setting

```
import MultiToggle from "react-multi-toggle";
import React from "react";
import "react-multi-toggle/style.css";

export default class ParentSwitch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: [
        {
          displayName: "Disabled",
          value: "disabled"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Pending",
          value: "pending"
        },
        {
          displayName: "Enabled",
          value: "enabled"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { options } = this.state;
    return (
      <MultiToggle
        options={options}
        selectedOption={this.props.parentSwitch}
        onSelectOption={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest that you group your child and parent under one component. Let say we name it `Settings`. Then, we create another component that will render a list of Settings and a button. This last component will hold the values of all Settings. Finally, each time the value of a `Setting Component Change`, we update the list. Checkout a sample [working app here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-perfect-jc8dj).

**App Component**

```
export default class App extends PureComponent {
  state = {};

  onSettingChange = (settingId, setting) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [settingId]: setting
    }));
  };

  onGetSettingValues = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Setting id="setting1" onChange={this.onSettingChange} />
        <Setting id="setting2" onChange={this.onSettingChange} />
        <button onClick={this.onGetSettingValues}>Get All Values</button>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

**Setting Component**

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from "react";
import ChildSwitch from "./ChildSwitch";
import ParentSwitch from "./ParentSwitch";

export default class Setting extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    parentVal: "disabled",
    switch1Val: "enabled",
    switch2Val: "disabled"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setParentSwitchValue();
  }

  setChildSwitchValue = (whichSwitch, selected) => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ ...prevState, [whichSwitch]: selected }),
      this.setParentSwitchValue
    );
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    const { id, onChange } = this.props;
    onChange(id, this.state);
  };

  setParentSwitchValue = () => {
    const { switch1Val, switch2Val } = this.state;
    const switchStates = [switch1Val, switch2Val];
    let parent = "pending";
    if (switchStates.every(val => val === "enabled")) {
      parent = "enabled";
    }
    if (switchStates.every(val => val === "disabled")) {
      parent = "disabled";
    }

    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ ...prevState, parentVal: parent }),
      this.handleChange
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { parentVal, switch1Val, switch2Val } = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="boxed">
          Parent Setting 1
          <ParentSwitch
            parentSwitch={parentVal}
            onSelect={this.setParentSwitchValue}
          />
          Setting 1:
          <ChildSwitch
            switchName={"switch1Val"}
            selected={switch1Val}
            onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
          />
          Setting 2:
          <ChildSwitch
            switchName={"switch2Val"}
            selected={switch2Val}
            onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
          />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Now If I have to get values of all these switches from an API, where would this API call be written?

Comment: You can implement componentDidMount on the `App Component ` and fetch your switches values there.

Comment: Yes definitely and you need the initial  value of your `Setting Componet Sate` to be those values your fetched from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your states into a single [context hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

```
const SettingsContext = createContext({state1, state2/* all your states in here*/);
```

You'll then wrap the whole thing into this context as such:

```
<SettingsContext.Provider>
  <App/>
</SettingsContext.Provider>
```

Now you can access the state in any of the children, parents etc. I suggest however not storing things like "disabled", "enabled" as strings, but rather store states as `{ enabled: true, pending: false}`

Comment: A snippet would be really useful here:) May be a sandbox forked from mine