# Dynamically add classes on based on state value and also change the children content based on parent's state change

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am implementing a setting page for an application. For each setting I have implemented a slider that has enabled(green) or disabled(red) state. But parent's settings is read only and is calculated based on the values of its children.

Parent should also be changeable ; Parent on green should turn all children to green ; On red it should be red ; But pending it should be as is

For this , I am using react-multi-toggle for this toggle switch.

Also If I want to dynamically add background color based on the state selected, how do I go about it. According to react-multi-toggle documentation know optionClass gets added to selected option. Now i want the selected color as the color for the entire container.. There's an option called "className" buy the class name doesn't get appended!

For this , I am using react-multi-toggle for this toggle switch.

Can someone help here?

Code sandbox :  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-perfect-wrx1w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add toggle children state when parent state change on the `Setting Component`.
Check out full [working sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-toggle-solution-perfect-7z08d). Key changes are

```
  // This function minght not be needed, if your few child switches
  // Just adding it in case you have multiple children
  setChildrenValue = value => {
    // state is immutable, we need clone it.
    const clonedState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
    for (let key in clonedState) {
      clonedState[key] = value;
    }

    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...clonedState }),
      this.handleChange
    );

    /**
         * Use this if your few children and remove code above
         * 
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            parentVal: value,
            switch1Val: value,
            switch2Val: value
          }), this.handleChange);
        */
  };

handleParentClick = parentVal => {
  if (parentVal === "pending") {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({ ...prevState, parentVal }),
      this.handleChange
    );
  } else {
    this.setChildrenValue(parentVal);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks much! How about the second one? Dynamically adding colors! Also on click of the button, values are coming wrong

Comment: Please create your class for styling and added them to the sandbox sample  :). It will be easier to help with sample code. You can add `classees name` to the 'setting component` state and bind them to the switches.

Comment: On click of button the values are not coming proper! Basically it should be true and false :)

Comment: @vjr, yes create some `CSS classes firt` so we can use them from javascript, your other issue on button click fixed.

Comment: @vjr now i got you, it should be simple, you can create background color for the `Setting component` and keep it in the sate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198285/discussion-between-morlo-mbakop-and-vjr).

Comment: Would you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608349/forming-the-components-based-on-the-array-of-objects-reactjs/57608723?noredirect=1#comment101675543_57608723