# Forming the components based on the array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

For a setting page for an application, I have implemented a slider that has enabled(green) or disabled(red) state. And parent's settings are calculated based on the values of its children.

```
//Getting the switches configuration inside componnetDidMount something like this

var obj = [
  {
    parent_header_name: "parent1",
    children_info: [
      {
        child_switch_name: "child1",
        isEnabled: true
      },
      {
        child_switch_name: "child2",
        isEnabled: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    parent_header_name: "parent2",
    children_info: [
      {
        child_switch_name: "child3",
        isEnabled: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    parent_header_name: "parent3",
    children_info: [
      {
        child_switch_name: "child4",
        isEnabled: false
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now based on this value, I need to form a grouping of parent and children something like this:

```
Label(the value should be parent_header_name) : Parent Switch Component
Label for children(children_switch_name) : Child Switch Component
```

Also on change of individual children switches toggling I need to get the info of that switch something like this:

For Example, Changing parent1's child1's to disabled

```
[
  {
    parent_header_name: "parent1",
    children_info: [
      {
        child_switch_name: "child1",
        isEnabled: false
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

In case parent1 turned to enabled I need to get all its chidren value

```
[
  {
    parent_header_name: "parent1",
    children_info: [
      {
        child_switch_name: "child1",
        isEnabled: true
      },
      {
        child_switch_name: "child2",
        isEnabled: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And when parents switch is toggled(when the parent is enabled, children will be enabled and when disabled children will be disabled;), I need to get the entire info of that parent

Also, I need to avoid toggling to "partial" state, the parent should only be enabled or disabled. "Partial" is only representational

For this, I am using react-multi-toggle for this toggle switch.

I have tried something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-switches-gxfx6

Comment: Please clarify: What exactly is your question? Your example seems to be working in my browser

Comment: @Taxel I have hard coded the  switch configurations ,l mean I am not generating the switches dynamically. Now based on the above array of objects, I need to bring the grouping of parent and child switches and getting the info of that switch on individual toggle.

Comment: Still confuse. I would consider rewrite the question in a clear-direct approach with more codes.

Comment: @iwaduarte There will be lot of code. So trying to avoid it . If you see the Settings.js render method, there is always one parent and two children for every group. But I have this use case where I can have any number of children for a parent across groups , So to render it dynamically based on the above array of objects,I need help . Hope you are getting me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your `Setting component` to allow it to renders your switches `name and value according` to the data received from the API. I will suggest you add an id to each of your `switches group`, that will ease your work. [Here is forked working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-switches-cefdu). The code can be uptimzed to befit your usecase. The key changes are done in the `Setting Component`.

**Setting Component Full code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import isEqual from "lodash.isequal";

import ChildSwitch from "./ChildSwitch";
import ParentSwitch from "./ParentSwitch";
import { PARTIAL } from "./constant";

export default class Setting extends Component {
  state = {
    parent: {
      value:
        this.props.children.length > 1
          ? PARTIAL
          : this.props.children[0].isEnabled
    },
    children: this.props.children
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setParentSwitchValue();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !isEqual(this.state, nextState);
  }

  setChildSwitchValue = (id, isEnabled) => {
    let clickedChild;
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        children: prevState.children.map(child => {
          if (child.id === id) {
            clickedChild = { ...child, isEnabled: isEnabled };
            return clickedChild;
          } else {
            return child;
          }
        })
      }),
      () => this.setParentSwitchValue(clickedChild)
    );
  };

  setParentSwitchValue = clickedChild => {
    const { children } = this.state;
    let parentVal = PARTIAL;

    if (children.every(({ isEnabled }) => isEnabled === true)) {
      parentVal = true;
    }
    if (children.every(({ isEnabled }) => isEnabled === false)) {
      parentVal = false;
    }

    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        parent: {
          value: parentVal
        }
      }),
      () => {
        this.handleChange();
        if (clickedChild) {
          const changed = {
            parent: {
              name: this.props.name,
              value: parentVal
            },
            child: clickedChild
          };
          console.log("This is the changed child", changed);
        }
      }
    );
  };

  setChildrenValue = value => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        parent: {
          value
        },
        children: prevState.children.map(child => ({
          ...child,
          isEnabled: value
        }))
      }),
      this.handleChange
    );
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    const { id, onChange } = this.props;
    onChange(id, this.state);
  };

  handleParentClick = parentVal => {
    if (parentVal !== PARTIAL) {
      this.setChildrenValue(parentVal);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { parent, children } = this.state;
    const { name } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="boxed">
        <span>{name}</span>
        <ParentSwitch
          childrenCount={children.length}
          parentSwitch={parent.value}
          onSelect={this.handleParentClick}
        />
        {children.map(({ id, name, isEnabled }) => (
          <Fragment key={id}>
            <span>{name}</span>
            <ChildSwitch
              switchName={id}
              selected={isEnabled}
              onSelect={this.setChildSwitchValue}
            />
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @vjr, You can get the setting you need on parent or child change. The functions handling those event are clearly named. Did your PO mentioned where you want to get and put those `settings values`?. As the for avoiding the pending state, I belive it is another question as the switches are red/green and their value are correct. I believe it might be a bug with `multi-toggle-select` or your can rethink your approach or restructure/opitimse the code as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: It's just the idea of making a server call sending what setting has been changed. Like if chaNge a parent need to understand which parent has changed and all its children value. Also what child has changed and its corresponding value :)

Comment: I see :), you can make your API call inside the `handleChange` function of the `Setting Component`. `Handle Change` is called each time there is a change on either parent or child switch.

Comment: If you want the swich not to shuffle, you cant sort them before you bind or you slice and insert an same index . Or event best youn can just reduce the children array on change event.

Comment: Might I ask why , why have you added this check "childCount === 1 " 
 inside getParentOptions() ? and also could you explain what is this inside Setting.js initial state object  " parent: {
      value:
        this.props.children.length > 1
          ? PARTIAL
          : this.props.children[0].isEnabled
    } "  ?

Comment: We don't want the parent to have partial state, if there is only one child. I added that to ensure `partial` is only available whe there is at least 2 children.

Comment: what is this inside Setting.js initial state object " parent: { value: this.props.children.length > 1 ? PARTIAL : this.props.children[0].isEnabled } " ?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it something like this:

- You have a top level `Settings` class that gets the settings object, saves it as its state and maps the array, creating `ParentSwitch` instances, passing the full parent setting including its children and a function that updates the state of `Settings` (for example with two integer arguments - parent index and child index) as props to the `ParentSwitch`
- The `ParentSwitch` then creates `ChildSwitch`es based on its props and passes the `updateSettings` function it got via its props to the `ChildSwitch`
- When a `ChildSwitch` is switched, it calls the function in `Settings`, switching the state of `Settings` which is passed to the `ParentSwitch` and the `ChildSwitch` where it is displayed

Is this understandable? Feel free to ask about anything that might be unclear

***Edit:***
Here's the working codepen. You have to layout it yourself, I have already spent more than enough time with this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-switches-jq0bp?fontsize=14
All of my code is in `Switches.js`

Comment: Although I have used the same names for the components you did, I would have to rewrite almost all your code. What about my explanation is unclear to you? I can provide code for the parts you don't understand

Comment: I think I pretty much understood it. I am just starting to think that I have already implemented some of the parts. May be your idea would really help here if you could edit the existing sandbox:)

Comment: Fine, I'm doing it. May take a few minutes (I am creating all new components)

Comment: What do you mean by "need to get the info of that switch something"? You can simply add that functionality to the `onUpdateSwitch` function in the `Settings` class.

Comment: Yes. But how will I understand if the parent or a child has changed? If child , then its value should be shown. If parent then the entire parent object should be shown:)

Comment: At the moment, only the children are changing. When you change a parent, all its children are switched. Also, where do you want to show that value? I sat down one hour and wrote almost 200 lines of code for you. Try to understand how my solution works and extend it yourself.

Comment: I added a console.log to the code so you see where you can start. Please mark this answer as correct.